Many one-to-one relationships pointing to the same model Django
I'm designing an application in Django where I have an Item model with numerous attributes for each item. I'm experiencing very poor performance in my application and I'm wondering if there are flaws in my setup that could be causing this issue. I am relatively new to Django, so any pointers would be greatly appreciated.
Currently, I have around 200 attribute models, each with optional one-to-one fields linked to an item via a foreign key as follows:
Attribute models:
class AttrBase(models.Model):
    prev_value = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    edited_by = models.ForeignKey(
        Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True
    )
    edited_on = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    options = None

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class ID(AttrBase):
    item = models.OneToOneField(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    name = "ID"
    tooltip = "..."
    group = "..."

class Height(AttrBase):
    item = models.OneToOneField(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    name = "Height"
    tooltip = "..."
    group = "..."

...more

I am also using a generic relationship to link to all of the groups, as follows:
class AttributeGroup(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ContentType,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        limit_choices_to={"app_label": "attributes"},
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(
        max_length=1000, default="TODO", null=True, blank=True
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.content_type)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name = self.content_type.name
        super(AttributeGroup, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

This is my Item model:
class Item(models.Model):
    """
    An item with related attributes.

    """

    program = models.ForeignKey(Program, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # part_number = models.CharField(max_length=25, db_index=True, unique=True)
    item_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_index=True)
    valid = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    leaf = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.program.program_code}-{self.part_number}"

    def get(self):
        """
        Return the item and all of its attributes.

        """
        # TODO: tune this?
        attributes_dict = {}
        attribute_groups = self.program.attribute_groups.all()
        attr_model_names = ["Name", "Type", "Identifier", "Level"]

        # Iterate over each attribute type
        for model_name in attr_model_names:
            model = apps.get_model("attributes", model_name)
            attr_instances = model.objects.filter(
                part=self, part__program__attribute_groups__in=attribute_groups
            )

            for attr_instance in attr_instances:
                attributes_dict[f"{model_name}"] = attr_instance.value

        return attributes_dict

    @classmethod
    def load(cls, program, part_number, attribute_vals=None):
        ...


Loading, creating, and reading part data is extremely slow. I have tried directly indexing all attributes, since (to my understanding) that should run in O(1) time, but CRUD operations on part data are still extremely slow.
